# Return void messing up reference parameter value

Tags: java, return, pass-by-reference, void

I wrote this code with the intention of chain being incremented each time `recurse()` is called. It does this, however (from what I saw with the debugger) each time `recurse()` reaches a return;, it decrements the value of `b`. This is project euler #14 if you want background on what I'm trying to do.

http://projecteuler.net/problem=14

```
private static void euler14()
{
    int currentstart=1000000;
    int longest = 0;
    int current=0;
    Integer chain=0;
    for(int i = currentstart; i>0; i--)
    {
        recurse(i,chain);
        if(chain > current)
        {
            current=chain;
            longest=i;
        }
        chain = 0;
    }
    System.out.print("Euler 14: " + longest + "\n");
}

private static void recurse(int a, Integer b)
{
    b++;
    if(a==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(a%2==0)
    {
        recurse((a/2), b);
    }
    else if(a%2==1)
    {
        recurse(((a*3)+1), b);
    }
    return;

}
```

Comment: I can't find a question. Anyhow, this `recurse(i,chain);` will never change the value of `chain` because `Integer` is immutable. I think you think `b++;` inside of `recurse()` will change it, but that will only affect the local variable `b`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see updates to `b` in your main method your need to return them back, when you reach end of recursion:

```
private static int recurse(int a, int b) {
    b++;
    if(a==1) return b;
    else if(a%2==0) return recurse((a/2), b);
    else if(a%2==1) return recurse(((a*3)+1), b);
    return b;
}
```

And in your main method you update your `chain` with new value:

```
chain = recurse(i,chain);
```

Comment: Perfect. I wish I had seen this answer sooner.

Answer (score 5):

Although the reference to `Integer` is passed (by value) to `recurse`, the object itself is immutable. When you do `b++`, the incremented value is assigned to `b` which is local to `recurse`. As soon as you return, the value goes back to the unchanged copy of `b` in the caller.

You can make `b` a `static int` variable, and drop it from the parameter list of `recurse` to fix the problem:

```
private static int b = 0;
private static void recurse(int a) {
    b++;
    if(a==1) {
        return;
    }
    if(a%2==0) {
        recurse((a/2), b);
    } else if(a%2==1) {
        recurse(((a*3)+1), b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. For further reading on the subject of immutable objects: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Comment: I tried to make `chain` static and replaced all instances of `b` in recurse() with `chain`. I'm getting the error `Illegal Modifier for variable chain, only final is permitted.` It seems I can only make it static outside of the method. I have a main method that executes all of the euler problems sequentially, so I would prefer to not add any code having to do with euler14 outside of euler14 except for it's initial call.

Comment: @JamesRoberts An inferior alternative would be to pass `int[1]` array as `b`, incrementing `b[0]++` instead. Arrays are mutable, so you don't need static variables. Finally, another option would be using `AtomicInteger`, a mutable class wrapping `int` and providing thread-safe operations on it (of course you wouldn't need any of its thread safety).

Answer (score 2):

Since your  method currently doesn't have a return value, you can use a return value for the number of steps.  Simply add 1 to each recursive step:

```
private static int recurse(int a) {
    if(a==1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a%2==0) {
        return 1 + recurse(a/2);
    } else if(a%2==1) {
        return 1 + recurse((a*3)+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is b referring to now?

Comment: @jalynn2: My mistake, removed :)